# Join 2 lists on empty strings with Anonymous types in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

I have 2 lists of different objects, that I need to join on 2 paramaters. Using Linq, I can join the lists with anonymous types.

```
from L1 in List1
join L2 in List2 on new { L1.Field1, L1.Field2 } equals new { L2.Field1, L2.Field2 }
select...
```

This works perfectly, except I want to include empty string matches on Field2. I've trimmed any whitespace from both lists also, so they are both empty strings.

Is this possible?

Comment: It should work fine. Please give a short but complete example of this not working.

Comment: Yep, if you want to match empty string with empty string this is fine, if you want empty string to be some sort of a wild-card, that's a different matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh solved it, Field1 in List1 was null, not empty. setting it to an emptry string when null fixed the problem.